# Which Governments publish their Ledgers and Accounts?

Tags: data-request, government, finance

I am interested in collecting financial data of Governments to analyse the Revenue and Expenditure against their Budgets. Ex:- [OpenReporting.com](https://openreporting.com), [OpenGov.com](http://OpenGov.com).. I have tried to find publicly available data sets from Governments but the success rate was very low. Are you aware of any such publicly available data sets of financial information with lowest level details going up to the transaction levels? If so please list them...

Answer (score 3):

### OpenSpending

This website collects datasets related to public spending by country:

https://openspending.org/

---

### Other resources

You should check [Open Budget Survey](http://survey.internationalbudget.org/#rankings)'s top 10's national websites for the data.

Among all-in-one place resources, see enigma.io. Here are some datasets:

- [United States 2014](https://app.enigma.io/table/us.gov.government-spending.contracts.2014)
- [United Kingdom 2014](https://app.enigma.io/table/gov.uk.government-spending.25k-departments.consolidated)

---

### Country-specific: Russia

Russia does well in opening its budget to the public: 10th place in [Open Budget Survey](http://survey.internationalbudget.org/#rankings).

You can find user-friendly interfaces for:

#### Budget

http://budget4me.ru/ (currently under construction)

#### Contracts

For all government units and SOEs. API and dataset access forms:

http://clearspending.ru/ (available in English)

Comment: Thank you for those new links.. enigma.io looks really interesting. budget4me.ru looks unavailable though..

Answer (score 2):

I think it's going to be hard to find all what you are looking for in one place. I would suggest starting with datasets from the UN.

Check on National Accounts at UN Data:
http://data.un.org/DataMartInfo.aspx

Check on 'Finance' section at OECD:
http://stats.oecd.org/

SIPRI has government military expenditures by country:
http://www.sipri.org/databases

Check on Public Sector category at WorldBank.org:
http://data.worldbank.org/topic/public-sector

Comment: these are all great andrew. add openspending to this list https://openspending.org/

Comment: Thank you Andrew for the efforts but those places do not have the financial data I am looking for. OpenSpending looks to have some data but the top figures do not match with numbers I have collected from other sources.. :(